# Dual boot install of Ubuntu 15.1 on Win 10 freezes at logo screen

Tags: dual-boot

I am trying to install, Dual Boot, Ubunut 15.1 on Win 10 machine. It boots from the USB but before even the language options it freeze on the purple Logo screen. My machine is Dell EXP 15 9550
The GPU is Nvidea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boot from the Ubuntu installation media.
Highlight Try Ubuntu without installing.
Press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot to the Live desktop.

Start the installation of the Ubuntu system.

When finished boot the installed system.
Highlight the Ubuntu GRUB menu entry.
Press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot the Ubuntu system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thanks again for this, but it freezes again.

Comment: @azyaser : Did you put a space at the end of the linux line before adding the parameter ? In case not repeat it with the space - in case yes, please try it with nomodeset instead of nouveau.modeset=0 ! :)

Comment: Yes I left space and tried the second command and freezes again. BTW this dell has two GPU, from Intel and Nvidea

Comment: @azyaser : Yes, I know ... please check whether you can deactivate the NVIDIA GPU in BIOS ... if yes, switch it off and after having installed the Ubuntu operating system and the NVIDIA drivers - switch it back on. :)

Comment: Before I do that, I installed Ubuntu using virtual box with RMA 4GB. Will I get same performance. I don't want to start missing this BIOS I am new to this kind of staff

Comment: @azyaser : Virtualization is something completely different - the performance of on bare metal installed Ubuntu will be even a lot better than in VirtualBox. :)

Comment: How can I disable Nvidia from the BIOS then? Do you have any link I can follow before I attempt again? And will I follow the normal procedure or what you have suggested as an alternative?

Comment: @azyaser : Sorry, I don't know this, you have to check it in the DELL manual ... every BIOS is configured differently ... and yes, please do everything as described in the answer. :)

Comment: I just checked and as per sell no option to disable it. My second alternative is to install it on my MacBook Air. I tried this too but it gives me that Windows download manager is installed because I had win 8 on it before I delete it. So how can I get rid of this message and what space is recommended because I am limited to 250GB for both OSX and Ubuntu

Comment: @azyaser : Sorry, I can't give you valid instructions on Apple products. Please ask this on an Apple forum. But it must be possible to install Ubuntu on your DELL machine ... please check every BIOS / UEFI setting. The instructions I gave you nearly never failed ! :)

Comment: I will check again. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Hi again, I managed to get past the freeze, started the installation and it asked for device for boot loader installation. Only option is /dev/sda, when selected and clicked on install now it gives an error no root file system defined, clicking in change or + or - gives and error

Comment: @azyaser : Nice to read this ... select / as mount point and ext4 as file system ... then it should work ! :)

Comment: Unfortunately I have no options to select from just /Dev/sad

Comment: @azyaser : I don't mean the boot loader location ... sda is okay ... I mean the partition scheme above where you have to select the location to install Ubuntu. :)

Comment: That is the thing. I wasn't introduced to any option to select I didn't even get the menu when it asks to install Ubuntu alongside win. BTW I haven't partitioned the SSD before this setup because I knew that Ubuntu will ask you to partition during setup

Comment: Just did. And to confirm again. I want Win 10 alongside Ubuntu

Comment: Hello, after all this miss I decided to buy a new HDD for my old Dell Latitude 6420, installation went well but I get the No Bootable Devices -- strike F1 to retry boot.......... I posted a new question, can you please help with this error?

Comment: Hi. I have managed to install it finally on my Dell xps. But I keep booting into black screen. I managed to boot bone into UBUNTU using no nomodeset to install the drivers but no luck after. Any thoughts?

Comment: @azyaser :  The only idea I have is to install the drivers as described in the answer ... alternatively you can install and try the latest official NVIIDIA drivers ->  http://askubuntu.com/questions/751613/new-to-ubuntu-gpu-has-disappeared-trying-to-use-cuda/751773#751773 This should work - it does in nearly all of the cases ! :)

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you have an idea how to boot into it? I keep getting the black screen even with nomodeset

Comment: You mean by end of Linux line? I am doing but keeps getting the black screen

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried and still gets the black screen

Comment: @azyaser : Maybe you can and have to deactivate the NVIDIA graphics in BIOS settings during the drivers installation or switch something else there ... otherwise unfortunately I am really running out of ideas ... :)

Comment: This worked when I tried to install Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10.