# New to Ubuntu, GPU has disappeared; trying to use CUDA

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

My laptop specs (Alienware 17 R2) say that I have an Intel integrated graphics chip and an NVIDIA GPU.

Now that I have installed Ubuntu, when I run `lspci | grep VGA` and `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`, the only item that appears is the integrated intel graphics chip.

Now I am looking at the NVIDIA website, and it is zero help.  There doesn't seem to be much support for the NVIDIA card on Linux...or at least much information about the support that does exist.

Can someone help me get my card back up and running with CUDA enabled?

I have an assignment using TensorFlow for deep learning due next month...and am kind of stumped getting all this hardware set up on the Linux system.

---

I do have a cloud drive and a Windows subscription, so I can switch...but I'd rather not, since it will take all weekend, and windows tends to break very quickly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct command to check whether you use the NVIDIA card is :

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

The output reads like this :

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'  
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)  
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 3501  
Kernel driver in use: i915  

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev a2)  
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 3501  
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

If it shows `Kernel driver in use: nvidia`, you use the NVIDIA card.

But first you have to install the NVIDIA drivers and Optimus support.

As your NVIDIA card is very new, you should install the latest drivers.

Open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  This worked perfectly.  Have to get CUDA set up for a project involving TensorFlow